# Issue in Update packages in R

Tags: r, package, install.packages

I updated all the packages on yesterday and now I'm getting an error in sqldf package as:

```
sqldf("select * from dt")
        Error in if (.allows_extensions(db)) { : 
        missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I tried using checkpoint() to access the existing version of all the packages which executing correct but again it failed:

```
checkpoint("2015-02-25")
       Scanning for loaded pkgs
       Scanning for packages used in this project
       Installing packages used in this project 

        There are binary versions available (and will be installed) but the
        source versions are later:
        Error in data.frame(binary = binvers, source = srcvers, row.names = bins,  : 
         duplicate row.names: downloader, sqldf, survey, plyr, ggplot2,scales, mapproj, RColorBrewer, maptools, raster, rgeos, fields, mgcv, stringr, spatstat, rgdal, RSQLite, MonetDB.R, RCurl, car, tree, ROCR, rattle, rpart, caret, randomForest, RODBC, reshape2, MASS, epiR, faraway, ggmap, maps, xlsx,  pROC, colorspace, quantmod, R2wd, checkpoint
```

Can someone please help me to get rid of this issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue go resolved after upgrading R version to 3.1.1 . Might be some package upgrade is not compatible with the earlier version of R.